# Exponent of convergence of $\{m+in \ | \ m, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}, (m,n) \neq (0,0) \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

The exponent of convergence $\rho$ of a sequence $\{z_{n}\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is defined as $$\rho = \inf \{\lambda \geq 0 \ | \sum_{n}\frac{1}{|z_{n}|^{\lambda}} < +\infty\}$$

My doubt is : what is the exponent of convergence of the sequence $$\{m+in \ |  \ m, \ n \in \mathbb{Z}, (m,n) \neq (0,0) \}$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, there are $8k$ points $m+in$ with $\max \{ \lvert m\rvert,\, \lvert n\rvert\} = k$. So we have

$$\frac{8k}{(\sqrt{2}\cdot k)^\lambda} \leqslant \sum_{\max \{ \lvert m\rvert,\, \lvert n\rvert\} = k} \frac{1}{\lvert m+in\rvert^\lambda} \leqslant \frac{8k}{k^\lambda},$$

from which it follows that

$$\sum_{m+in\in \mathbb{Z}[i]\setminus\{0\}} \frac{1}{\lvert m+in\rvert^\lambda} < \infty \iff \lambda > 2.$$